# Spring JMS 2-phase-commit in java SE

Tags: spring, jms, 2phase-commit

I am not running under Java EE.

I want to have an XA transaction using Spring to share a transaction between DB and JMS.

Does spring provide such a functionality or must I use an external transaction manager such as Atomikos?

I use currently the DataSourceTransactionManager for the DB, and I see I can also use the JMSTransactionManager. Do they work together? Not clear from the documentation as JtaTransactionManager is mentioned.

Please advise.

Yair

Answer (score 1):

Spring only provides a framework for transaction management, it as such doesn't provide any transaction manager. If you are running your application outside a Java EE container and you need a transaction between resources like a DB and JMS, you have to use an external TransactionManager like Atomikos or JOTM (Java Open Transaction Manager).

You might want to refer to http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-xa.html for more details on XA using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

they are resource local, but Spring does support XA (see this post for explanation *and* example code) : http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/